# Accessing data in Google Maps PHP with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having trouble correctly accessing data in Google Maps API php.

Heres what example data looks in php:

```
{"destination_addresses":["Destination address"],"origin_addresses":["Origin address"],"rows":[{"elements":[{"distance":{"text":"3.3 km","value":3314},"duration":{"text":"6 mins","value":334},"status":"OK"}]}],"status":"OK"}
```

Heres my .js:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var start = $("#start").val(); //gets start and end values from input fields, and passes them to .php which is not visible here.
        var end = $("#end").val();

        $.ajax({url: "googlemaps.php", 
            method: "GET", 
            data : { "start" : start, "end" : end },
            success: function(result) { 
            print(result);                      
        },
            error: function(xhr){
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }               
        });

    });  
});

function print(result){
    var length = "";
    for(var i = 0;i < result.rows.length;i++){
    length += result.rows[i].text+ "<br/>";

        $("#div").html(length);
    }}
```

It should calculate the distance between two addresses, and it currently returns unidentified (which is ok), since

```
length += result.rows[i].text+ "<br/>";
```

is not correct. I have no idea how to access value "text":"3.3 km", or it's equivalent in my code. I know it is an object inside "distance", which is an array item of "elements", which is an array item of "rows".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its structured like:

`rows[0].elements[0].distance.text`

You might not need the loop, but if you were to use it you would do something like.

```
for (var i = 0;i < result.rows.length; i++) {
  for (var k = 0;k < result.rows[i].elements.length; k++) {
    length += result.rows[i].elements[k].distance.text + "<br/>";
  }
}

$("#div").html(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is `result`, then you can access the distance by using this:

```
var distance = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
```